# Odd behavior for array[value]

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to check if a member (from members array) is an officer (from officers array) and yet even if i copy the exact known value it is not matching. I must be missing something.

[image]

```
    getClanMemberInfo() {
  this.clanMemberInfo = [];
  console.log(this.clan.members);
  console.log(this.clan.officers);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.clan.members.length; i++) {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("profiles")
      .doc(this.clan.members[i])
      .get()
      .then(profile => {
        var info = profile.data();
        console.log(this.clan.officers['sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2'])
        if (this.clan.officers[this.clan.members[i]]) {
          console.log("Hi officer");
          info.officer = true;
        } else {
          console.log("BAT");
          info.officer = false;
        }
        this.clanMemberInfo.push(info);
      });
  }
}
```

You can see I put the exact value in for the console.log and its still undefined but from the console.logs above they are not empty.

I do not understand why a simple comparison is not matching.

[image]

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.clan.members.length; i++) {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("profiles")
      .doc(this.clan.members[i])
      .get()
      .then(profile => {
        var info = profile.data();

        for (var o = 0; o < this.clan.officers.length; o++) {
          console.log(this.clan.officers[o]);
          console.log(this.clan.members[0]);
          if (this.clan.officers[o].toString() === this.clan.members[i]) {
            console.log("Hi officer");
            info.officer = true;
          } else {
            console.log("BAT");
            info.officer = false;
          }
        }

        this.clanMemberInfo.push(info);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I am using those values to push into an array for viewing and the members do show up just false for the officer part.

Comment: If you want to access from array , you should pass the index and not the value. That is why it is printing as undefined. You can make a map for the same and use it as you are using now.

Comment: if you change `console.log(this.clan.officers['sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2'])` to `console.log(this.clan.officers[1])`, what does it show ?, does it still show `undefined` or it prints out `sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2`

Comment: yes it does because there is only 1 officer. Officers[0] comes back with an ID.

Answer (score 0):

First of all `Array` values can be accessed using `index` number.

```js
getClanMemberInfo() {
  this.clanMemberInfo = [];
  console.log(this.clan.members);
  console.log(this.clan.officers);
  for (var i = 0; i < this.clan.members.length; i++) {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("profiles")
      .doc(this.clan.members[i])
      .get()
      .then(profile => {
        var info = profile.data();
        // you are looping using members length so use members below with index
        console.log(this.clan.members[i])
        // you can check if your member is an officer or not by below line
        if (this.clan.officers.includes(this.clan.members[i])) {
          console.log("Hi officer");
          info.officer = true;
        } else {
          console.log("BAT");
          info.officer = false;
        }
        this.clanMemberInfo.push(info);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated code with `officers.includes()`. You can try that as well.

Comment: weird its not working still, is it being a observer anything?

Answer (score 0):

it seems to be this.clan.officers is an array of strings, not a dictionary.

so this.clan.officers[0] is defined as 'sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2'

but this.clan.officers['sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2'] is pure gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a given string exists inside an array of values, you can use [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

`isOfficer = officers.includes('sJUZKKhLDvPDBWPILdzCN9waFpb2');`

Comment: Its not liking it still for some reason, does it being an observer matter ?